# Lua script failed to load .dll written by C

Tags: c, dll, lua

Recently, I started to learn Lua language. And when I wanted to call C functions in Lua, I ran into some trouble.
I wrote a .c file which defines some functions, and then compiled and linked it to produce a .dll file. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "luainc.h"

static int l_func1(lua_State *L)
{
    double d1 = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
    double d2 = luaL_checknumber(L, 2);
    lua_pushnumber(L, d1 * d1 + d2 * 2);
    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg mylib[] =
{
    {"func1", l_func1},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_mylib(lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_newlib(L, mylib);
    return 1;
}
```

Then, I loaded it through my Lua script by:

```
local mylib = require("mylib")
```

However, it failed with following errors:
lua: error loading module 'mylib' from file '.\mylib.dll': %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Who knows the reason and can help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Try `extern int __declspec(dllexport) luaopen_mylib(lua_State *L)`. If compiling with MSVC or a C++ compiler try `extern "C" int __declspec(dllexport) luaopen_mylib(lua_State *L)`

Comment: Are you trying to load a 32-bit DLL from a 64-bit program or vice versa?

Comment: @immibis Yes, you are right. It was my problem of mixing 32-bit and 64-bit. I fixed it. However, a new problem appeared. lua: error loading module 'array' from file '.\array.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. I think I have written luaopen_mylib() in my code. How can I fix that?

Comment: Do what greatwolf said. And remember that mylib has to be the actual library name so change it to array if your library is called array.

Comment: Thank you so much. My code works now.